# How to export and import a app-docker and a mysql-docker, which are depending on each other?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, containers

I have a spring-boot-app, which depends on data in a mysql-container. So first I have to run the mysql-image and then my app is able to start. I dockerized the app as well so both can communicate with each other. That works very well.

I have tried to start both containers and then send them in separate containers to my college. But he is not able to run the app, because the mysql container has not any data anymore. He gets a JDBC-Exception.

Is it possible to do that and if yes, how?

Thanks :)

Comment: can you add exception stack ?

Comment: 2019-09-26 15:01:00.574 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]

Comment: I found the solution :)

https://medium.com/@tomsowerby/mysql-backup-and-restore-in-docker-fcc07137c757

Comment: you can put your solution in Answer, that help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a sprint-boot application without connect MySQL docker container. so you need to connect local db.with pass environment variables on sprint-boot